# d3.js runtime error after upgrade to Angular 15

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, node-modules

After upgrading our application from Angular 13 to Angular 15, a d3.js error started to show up. The ng server command  runs successfully but the following error happens when we try to use the app in the browser:

`d3.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')`

The offending line is `var d3_document = this.document;`. The use of 'this' here should refer to 'window' I believe, but for some reason it is undefined. d3.js is bundled in vendor.js and it is referred in the page like so `<script src="vendor.js" type="module">`. I think it's because the type is module. In the scripts.js, which is referred like `<script src="scripts.js" defer></script>` (so no type=module), I've put `console.log(this)` and it prints the `window` object.

We also include d3.js in angular.json scripts list but it seems that the node_modules d3.js is the one being used, and the one in scripts.js is ignored. We don't use d3 directly, a dependency of our project uses dc.js, crossfilter2 and d3.js to provide angular chart components that we use.

With the upgrade of Angular the target in tsconfig.json is set to ES2022 and it was ES2020 previously.
Is there a way to put d3.js only in scripts.js or to transform node_modules d3.js references to `this` be replaced by `window` or `globalThis`?

I've tried to changed target in tsconfig.json file and also .browserslistrc to include a old browser like ie 11.
The problem is fixed manually replacing `this` in node_module/d3/d3.js by `window` but that is not a solution.
Tried adding a babel.config.json file to the app file tree and enable the "loose" mode but I don't know if that is even being applied to the Angular project:

```
{
    "sourceType": "unambiguous",
    "presets": [[
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
            "loose": true
        }
    ]],
    "overrides": [
        {
            "test": "d3/d3.min.js",
            "sourceType": "script"
        },
        {
            "test": "d3/d3.js",
            "sourceType": "script"
        },
        {
            "test": "d3/index.js",
            "sourceType": "script"
        },
        {
            "test": "dc_scripts.js",
            "sourceType": "script"
        },
        {
            "test": "vendor.js",
            "sourceType": "script"
        }
    ]
}
```